# Why can't tranfer file into the remote vps with expect?

Tags: shell, expect

The expect has been installed, `it_a_test` is the vps password.

```
scp  /home/wpdatabase_backup.sql   root@vps_ip:/tmp
```

The command can transfer file  /home/wpdatabase_backup.sql  into my vps_ip:/tmp.

Now i rewrite the process into the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn scp  /home/wpdatabase_backup.sql   root@vps_ip:/tmp
expect "password:"
send it_is_a_test\r
```

Why can't transfer my file into remote vps_ip with expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, `expect` will work with two feasible commands such as `send` and `expect`. In this case, if `send` is used, then it is mandatory to have `expect` (in most of the cases) afterwards. (while the vice-versa is not required to be mandatory)

This is because without that we will be missing out what is happening in the spawned process as `expect` **will assume that you simply need to send one string value and not expecting anything else from the session**, making the script exits and causing the failure.

So, you just have to add one `expect` to wait for the closure of the `scp` command which can be performed by waiting for `eof` (End Of File).

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn scp  /home/wpdatabase_backup.sql   root@vps_ip:/tmp
expect "password:"
send "it_is_a_test\r"
expect eof; # Will wait till the 'scp' completes.
```

**Note :**

The default timeout in expect is 10 seconds. So, if the `scp` completes, within 10 seconds, then no problem. Suppose, if the operation takes more than that, then `expect` will timeout and quit, which makes failure in `scp` transfer. So, you can set increase timeout if you want which can be modified as

```
set timeout 60; # Timeout is 1 min
```